# Excel - Return Cell's Value Based Upon Another Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a purchasing report that needs to be processed each week that, among other things, tracks sales that are lost over the preceding time period. We do this using a separate sheet for lost sales that is then referenced in the primary sheet through a formula.

The reference sheet for our lost sales is broken down as follows:

```
Item ID        Qty Remaining        Invoice No
00001          2                    40404
00002          9                    50505
00003          0                    60606
```

We've been using this formula in our primary reporting sheet:

```
 =COUNTIF(Table2,[@[Item ID]])
```

To pull the information into the 'Lost Sales' column of our primary sheet itself, which is broken down like this:

```
Item ID        ...        Lost Sales
00001          ...        2
00002          ...        9
00003          ...        0
```

The downside to this is that instead of referencing the Item ID and then pulling the quantity from the Qty Remaining cell, it requires someone (me) to manually repeat the item ID the appropriate number of times. Using our example from before, this is what it would end up looking like:

```
Item ID        Qty Remaining        Invoice No
00001          2                    40404
00001
00002          9                    50505
00002
00002
00002
00002
00002
00002
00002
00002
```

What I'm looking for is a way to reference the Item ID and then just pull the value from Qty Remaining without the need for manual processing of the data, which is time-consuming and frustrating given the size of the actual sheets we work with. I've tried modifying the COUNTIF, and building new INDIRECT statements, but neither of those things have worked for me.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you are adding the duplicate lines to the table itself?

Comment: As it's set up now, that's exactly what I'm doing. Which obviously isn't ideal, so I'm trying to find a way to just programmatically skip it and still get the info we need.

Comment: That will take vba.  A formula will not do this.

Comment: Could you share the initial data and desired resulting data samples and/or explain which is which.

Comment: @vbasic2008 Basically what I'm trying to do is get the value from Qty Remaining in the example into another sheet in the same workbook, using Item ID as a common reference point. I'm going to update the question to clarify.